# hibernate 4 session log4j

Tags: java, hibernate, log4j

All hello! 
I am used Hibernate 4.2.
I want to see all opening and closings of sessions in log file.To the instruction in what class and a method there was an opening/closing.

My beans:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/>
```

I have tried to use the logs from a package

```
 org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
```

As a result I have received:

```
  [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter] - Using SessionFactory 'sessionFactory' for OpenSessionInViewFilter
  [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter] - Opening Hibernate Session in OpenSessionInViewFilter
```

It not that I expected. From what packages it is possible to use the log to receive desirable result?

Thanks)

Answer (score 2):

You can enable the logging of hibernate Sessions(opening and closing), by adding the following entry to your log4j.properties file: `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl=TRACE`
and set the rootLogger level to TRACE:`log4j.rootLogger=TRACE`

This will generate logs similar to the below in your log file:

```
(SessionImpl.java:<init>:322) - Opened session at timestamp: 14588196881
(SessionImpl.java:close:357) - Closing session
```

Comment: This generates a lot of logs